# Applecare Validity for Macbook in Turkey

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare

I am getting conflicting answers (even from the Apple itself) about the validity of the applecare plan for Macbook Pro (purchased from US) in Turkey. I know that there are Apple stores in Istanbul and that Apple gives technical assistance there. However, some says that applecare is not valid in Turkey. They say that in order to benefit from the applecare plan I should either mail my computer to US or bring it to US or perhaps to some nearby EU country where the plan is valid. On the contrary some says that applecare is completely valid for MacBooks in Turkey (though not for Iphones, Ipads, etc.). I would be grateful if I can have the correct answer and, if the plan is valid in Turkey then how the process works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apple products have a global warranty, so you *should* be covered.

You need to contact Apple directly - someone there will be able to organise something for you. You may need to provide proof of purchase, so have that ready (scan it in if you haven't got a digital copy).

For your info, below is an experience that may shed some light on this for you.

I recently helped a lady who purchased a new iPhone from a local online store. About 10 months later the iPhone developed a fault, and while it was definitely under warranty, it took a while to establish this fact because the serial number came up as having been purchased in Thailand, and because it was dated about 7 weeks earlier than when she had purchased it.

In this case, she needed to show her purchase receipt to correct the commencement date for her warranty, as it was originally showing as only 8 days remaining compared to the two months she thought she had left. It did get all sorted, but the issue had to get escalated before it was resolved.

So, if it was me, I would visit [Apple's contact page for Turkey](https://www.apple.com/tr/contact/) and contact them directly via phone to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that it has been quite a while since this question has been asked/answered, my wife and I just had this exact situation.  Maybe this will help someone who comes across a search for this question.

We have a 2018 MacBook Pro that had 2 issues: 1) a recalled SSD and 2) a failed battery.  We had purchased the MacBook in California last summer with AppleCare and have now moved to Istanbul.

We took the MacBook into the Apple Store in the Zorlu Center mall after making a Genius Bar appointment. They looked up the serial number and it was completely repaired in just a few days.

They replaced the entire lower 1/2 of the case and it even came back (thankfully) with a US keyboard.  They even had personnel that spoke English, as I'm still struggling with Turkish.

Super service!